# Processing Split (server)

Tags: string, split, server, client, processing

I am doing 2player game and when I get informations from server, it's in format "topic;arg1;arg2" so if I am sending positions it's "PlayerPos;x;y".
I then use split method with character ";".
But then... I even tried to write it on screen "PlayerPos" was written right, but it cannot be gained through if.

This is how I send info on server:

```java
server.write("PlayerPos;"+player1.x+";"+player1.y);
```

And how I accept it on client:

```java
String Get=client.readString();
  String [] Getted = split(Get, ';');
  fill(0);
  text(Get,20,20);
  text(Getted[0],20,40);
if(Getted[0]=="PlayerPos"){
  text("HERE",20,100);
  player1.x=parseInt(Getted[1]);
  player1.x=parseInt(Getted[2]);
}
```

It writes me "PlayerPos;200;200" on screen, even "PlayerPos" under it. But it never writes "HERE" and it never makes it into the if.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `==` when comparing `String` values. Use the `equals()` function instead:

```java
if(Getted[0].equals("PlayerPos")){
```

From [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/String.html):

> To compare the contents of two Strings, use the `equals()` method, as in `if (a.equals(b))`, instead of `if (a == b)`. A `String` is an `Object`, so comparing them with the `==` operator only compares whether both `Strings` are stored in the same memory location. Using the `equals()` method will ensure that the actual contents are compared. (The [troubleshooting reference](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Troubleshooting#Why_don.27t_these_Strings_equal.3F) has a longer explanation.)

Comment: Thank you! I am so silly, I always forget about this >.<

Comment: @DavidAliFoxKnapčok No problem. Keep in mind that you can upvote and accept helpful answers, if you feel like it.